# Sending multiple HTTP GET Requests to same host causes aiohttp client to get stuck

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am trying to send multiple requests to the same host (e.g., I am trying to download 20 - 50 files from using six TCP connections from the same host)

This is done in a loop, meaning that after I finish downloading one set of files code proceed and download a new set of files and so on.

The problem appears when I have over 20 files to download. A client gets stuck and it does not release process. Furthermore, I checked with Wireshark and everything seems working fine, all requests are sent (GET) and all responses are received (200/OK). It seems there is an issue with either way the logic is implemented or bug in the library itself.

Timeouts are always preceded with this message:

asyncio - INFO - poll 14805.463 ms took 14808.587 ms: timeout

I am using aiohttp version 3.5.4 and Python 3.7.2

For web server, I am using waitress + Flask for serving files

When I switch to HTTP 1.0 it works fine. It seems problem occurs with persistent connections. I would prefer to keep a connection open

import aiohttp
import logging
import always

async def download_site(session, url):

```
 response = await session.request(method="GET", url=url[0], params=url[1], ssl=False, expect100=False)
 async with response:
     stat = response.status 
     response.release()
     return stat
```

async def retrieve_file(_file, run):

```
headers = {"Connection": "keep-alive"}
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=6), raise_for_status=True) as session:
    start_time = time.time()
    # we first download main file (actually this is not always one)
    num_main_file = 1   


    for main_obj in range(1, num_main_obj+1):

            # auxilary files
            # list object is a list of auxilary file names which we use to construct a list of requests
            inline_objs = [["127.0.0.1:8080", {'user': '1', 'file': str(_file), 'run':str(run), 'obj':i}] for i in list_obj]


            # download main file
            main_list = [["127.0.0.1:8080", {'user': '1', 'file': str(_file), 'run':str(run), 'obj':"main_%d"%main_obj}]]
            tasks = []
            for url in main_list:
                task = asyncio.create_task(download_site(session, url))
                tasks.append(task)
            res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
            logging.debug("main obj: " + str(res))

            # download auxilary files - this is where problem happens
            tasks = []
            for url in inline_objs:
                task = asyncio.create_task(download_site(session, url))
                tasks.append(task)
            res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
            logging.debug("inline objs: " + str(res))

    duration = int(1000*(time.time() - start_time))
    logging.info('Load File_%d: %d'%(_file, duration))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
```

async def wrap(_file, run):
    try:
        # added timeout as by default it will get stuck for around 300 seconds
        await asyncio.wait_for(retrieve_file(*file, run), timeout=15.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        logging.info('File*%d: TIMEOUT'%(_file))

def main(**kwargs):

```
# we try this five times
for run in range(1, 6):

    for _file in range(1, num_files+1):

        # create session
        asyncio.run(wrap(_file, run), debug=True)
        # sleep for 2 seconds
        time.sleep(2.0)
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
# set logging level
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
main()
```

Here is the output from always log when it is working ok:

root - DEBUG - main obj: [200] - downloaded main file

asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=13 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=14 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=15 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=16 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=17 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14959.065 ms took 0.817 ms: 1 events
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14956.670 ms took 0.009 ms: 1 events
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=15 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14948.205 ms took 0.046 ms: 1 events
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14946.960 ms took 0.010 ms: 2 events
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=13 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=14 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14935.982 ms took 0.053 ms: 1 events
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14935.441 ms took 0.227 ms: 1 events
root - DEBUG - inline objs: [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200] - downloaded all aux files using 6 TCP connections
root - INFO - Load File_7: 65

This is when the timeout appears:

root - DEBUG - main obj: [200]- downloaded main file

asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=14 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=15 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=13 read=idle write=> pauses reading
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=14 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=16 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14825.699 ms took 0.205 ms: 1 events
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14824.048 ms took 0.017 ms: 5 events
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=12 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14817.963 ms took 0.008 ms: 2 events
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=15 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - connect  to ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
asyncio - DEBUG -  connected to 127.0.0.1:8080: (<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=17 read=polling write=>, )
asyncio - DEBUG - poll 14807.080 ms took 0.948 ms: 1 events
asyncio - INFO - poll 14805.463 ms took 14808.587 ms: timeout - this always appears
root - INFO - File_8: TIMEOUT